# Android camera embedded in a frame

Tags: android, camera, frame

I want to take a picture with my app, but I want to run the camera inside a fragment in a frame. Is it possible to accomplish that?
Any help appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is Possible to Write your Own Camera Module using SurfaceView see the Android Documentation
for [Building a Camera App](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html), [Example](http://capycoding.blogspot.in/2012/06/custom-camera-application.html)

Comment: Thank you, this might be the way!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a frame to the picture taken, you must post-process the captured image, whatever method you choose - be it via intent, or Camera.takePicture().

If you want the preview to appear inside a rectangular frame,  you simply create an xml layout to your liking, frame included,  and a surfaceView positioned where you need it.

If your frame has some curls or curves on the inside,  your preview surface should be z-ordered under this frame (which will include transparent areas).